# Can I set font-weight for <h5> tag or h5 bootstrap class?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to use either  tag or .h5 bootstrap class to increase font-size, but I don't want text bold.

```
<p class="h5 font-weight-light">Whatever</p>
```

and

```
<h5 class="font-weight-light">Whatever</h5>
```

and

```
<h5 style="font-weight: 300">Whatever</h5>
```

Doesn't work for me. They are all bold.

Do you have any idea how to make it work?

Comment: Please add you `light font` ttf into you html or import from online tools. your files don't has light weight font so its not working..

Comment: You need to have the lighter font to be able to make the font light. As an example, if you are using the font named 'Roboto' from google fonts, you need to have the below inside your head tag `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400" rel="stylesheet">` and in your css `body{font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;}`. Once this is done your font-weight: 300 will work. Hope this make sense to you.

Comment: Try in CSS h5 { font-weight: 300!important; }

Comment: they are number of font face that can be used

Answer (score 1):

You are missing !important for that style to be active, so:

```
<h5 style="font-weight:300 !important;">Whatever</h5>
```

It would be best to put that CSS in a separate file not directly in html.

There is no need to use h5 when you can just set the font size directly.

```
style { font-size: 2rem ; }
```